# PDF editor: Zoom operation in overview mode

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf

I use [PDF Expert](https://pdfexpert.com) in overview mode:

[image]

but I find that the width of every page is fixed, I cannot zoom them out and in.

Is there a way to perform zoom operation in overview mode in PDF Expert? Or is there any alternative PDF editor which possess this functionality?